# How are Objects rendered or updated, when there's a Pool class?

Tags: resource-management, architecture

I have a State (Title State for example), that has the ResourcePool (getImage();getSound(); etc.)
and a list of the GameObjects.

How do GameObjects get access to the Resources in the Pool they need?

Should the GameObjects have a reference to their resources at construction time or possibly even the pool itself?

The GameObjects render/update themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I would make `ResourcePool`'s methods static. If the performance is not an issue, I would suggest accessing the resources by their name, for the sake of readability.

*ResourcePool.hpp*

```
class ResourcePool
{
    static Image & getImage(std::string & filename);
    static Sound & getSound(std::string & filename);

    static std::unordered_map<std::string, Image &> imagePool;
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, Sound &> soundPool;
};
```

Somewhere in your code

```
texture.setBackground(ResourcePool::getImage("player.png"));
```

It also comes handy if you allow modding - modders just use the transparent access by filename, and if the resource doesn't exist, you can let them know (exceptions, returning error object, or whatever suits you best).

```
ResourcePool::getImage(filename)
{
    auto iter = imagePool.find(filename);

    // If we have already loaded the image, return the reference
    if(iter != imagePool.end())
    {
        return iter->second;
    }
    // If we haven't loaded the image, try to load it
    else
    {
        Image * loaded = loadImage(filename);

        // If the image cannot be loaded, throw an exception (pass an error object/whatever)
        if(loaded == nullptr)
        {
            throw ResourceNotFound(filename);
        }
        // Otherwise insert it into the pool and return it
        else
        {
            imagePool[filename] = *loaded;
            delete loaded;
            return imagePool[filename];
        }
    }
}
```

It's also useful if you have too many resources - you can preload the most used ones and the rest is loaded on demand. On top of that, if you run out of memory, you can remove those which weren't accessed for the longest time.

Comment: So it's okay to use static methods for resources?
Let's say I have a SoundPlayer and a MusicPlayer and a Objects has some sounds assigned. should the SoundPlayer have a playSound(String file); method which is static, too?

Comment: @Raildex - `SoundPlayer` in this case should have just `Sound &`, obtained from `getSound("filename.ogg")`.  The `playSound()` method doesn't need to be static (and cannot be, in case you have multiple SoundPlayers), it just needs to *access* `getSound(filename)`.

Comment: That's my problem. My GameObject may have a `String attackSound;`.

how Do I send this sound to the SoundPlayer? Only the `State`, where the GameObject lies, has a reference to the SoundPlayer

Comment: In your state you should call:
`soundPlayer.play(ResourcePool::getSound(object->getAttackSound()))`.
However, it will take a while, since it will have to load the first time. The quickest (although very ugly) approach to fix this is to call `ResourcePool::getSound(object->getAttackSound())`. Note that this approach may be buggy in multi-thread environment.

Comment: But GameObject is the general Class. Entities inherit from GameObject. For example a Player can have a attackSound,  but a Door may have a doorSound.  What I need is a way to send the Sound from the Entity to the SoundPlayer.

Comment: @Raildex 
That is no problem at all. The method name served only as an example. You can have your `GameObject` class with your `getObjectSound()` method and in the classes that inherit from it you call again `getObjectSound()`, now appropriately overridden.
Just change `getAttackSound()`  to `getObjectSound()` in the previous example I gave you and it's done.

Of course, not seeing your code makes me only guess.

Comment: My code looks something like this: [link](http://pastebin.com/RAsneAVp)

What I need is a "bridge" between the Entity and the resourceManager or SoundPlayer.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution to having the resource pool static is implementing the resource pool as a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

- leave the methods as they are
- make the constructor private
- add a variable `private static ResourcePool instance`
- add a public `getInstance()` method which checks if `instance` was already created, and when not creates it. It then returns `instance`.

Any class which needs the resource pool would obtain the instance using `ResourcePool::getInstance()`.

The advantage of this pattern is that it allows you to do complex initialization of the resource pool when it is first used, even when the programming language you use doesn't support static constructors. It also provides you with more flexibility by giving you the option to create a new class which extends ResourcePool without sharing the state with the original class.